# Spring Roo + Vaadin Plugin: Running on Tomcat server

Tags: tomcat, spring-roo, vaadin

Using this tutorial https://vaadin.com/springroo, i was able to get a Spring Roo project started and configured with Vaadin add-on. I am having trouble running this application on a tomcat server in a container. I have tomcat already installed in my eclipse environment and configured but dont know what the command is in Spring ROO shell that allows me to run this project?

How do you set up tomcat with a Spring Roo project using the vaadin add-on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To deploy your application in a Web container during project development you have several options available:

Deploy from your shell / command line (without the need to assemble a war archive):
run 'mvn tomcat:run' in the root of your project (not inside the Roo shell) to deploy to a Tomcat container
run 'mvn jetty:run' in the root of your project (not inside the Roo shell) to deploy to a Jetty container

[Beginning With Roo](http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/reference/html/beginning.html) character **2.9. Step 6: Loading the Web Server**

**EDIT 1**

If you have not installed maven, read [this article](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/what-is-maven-and-how-do-i-install-it.html?page=2)
If you want run your project using jetty, read  [this article](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Maven+Jetty+Plugin)

Comment: does this mean i need to have Maven installed to run those commands. If so, how do i integrate an already created Spring Roo project?

Comment: I downloaded STS which fixed everything, i was trying to set Roo up in eclipse helios. Thanks